How can I show the ñ character in the netbeans output console?
The netbeans output console does not show the ñ characters. Show a rare symbol instead. When doing a System.out.println("Niño"); This is what it shows: Ni�o

The issue is related to character encoding . Please ensure you are using UTF-8 when i had this encoding i can see the correct output .

Steps to check the character encoding you are using is UTF-8 or not :

Right click your file and go to properties :



And check encoding at the bottom , ensure it is UTF-8 .



If it is not UTF-8 please select it as UTF-8.

Note: Iam using Apache Netbeans IDE 23

i already have this configuration in my project (UTF-8) but still not works.
